# spring-batch job throws "column reference is ambiguous"

Tags: java, sql, spring, postgresql, spring-batch

I'm using spring batch in java.

I have two tables table1 and table2 in my postgres db.
first table have one column 'lid' and second table have lid and bid columns.

my spring config looks like:

```
<property name="selectClause">
    <value> <![CDATA[
        SELECT f.lid, r.bid
     ]]>
    </value>
</property>
<property name="fromClause">
    <value> <![CDATA[
        FROM table1 f left outer join (select distinct bid, lid from table2) AS r ON f.lid=r.lid
        ]]>
    </value>
</property>
<property name="whereClause">
    <value><![CDATA[
      WHERE f.lid >= :start and f.lid <= :end
    ]]>
    </value>
</property>
<property name="sortKey" value="lid" />
```

The above setting throws exceptions when I run the batch job.

below are the list of exceptions I encountered when tried different settings.

1) when I ran the job (as per settings above), I get below error:
"org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "lid" reference is ambiguous"

2) I tried overcoming this issue by adding ", f.lid lidtemp" in selectClause and then changed sortKey to lidtemp and then I saw below error:
"nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "lidtemp" does not exist"

3) when I changed sortKey to f.lid, it complained: "column f.lid doesn't exist in the ResultSet"

below is the query generated while running the job which resulted in issue #1 above:
    SELECT f.lid, r.bid FROM table1 f
left outer join (select distinct bid,lid from table2) AS r ON f.lid=r.lid WHERE f.lid >= 54734 and f.lid <= 54734 ORDER BY lid ASC LIMIT 1000

when I ran above query in pgAdmin, it worked perfectly fine.

I tried several tricks, it finally came down to the issue that spring batch is adding extra condition in the where clause: " AND ((lid > ?))"

I already have condition on f.lid.
any reason why its being added and how to get rid of it?

Comment: have you tried settings `sortKey` as `f.lid`?